# Why render method run twice in class component without any state been included?

Tags: reactjs, class, components, render

I am new to react Js I am practising class component I noticed that it is rendering twice when I console log the render method can any one explain me why it is happening code is given below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
render() {
    console.log('check');
    return (
      <div>
          Count
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter
```

Comment: Child component re-renders with parent. Check whether its parent is rendering

Comment: @Vaibhav you mean to say that first chlid renders itself than it re-renders with its parent component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this happens because of [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

As per the ReactJS official docs,

Conceptually, React does work in two phases:

- The **Render phase** determines what changes need to be made to e.g. the DOM. During this phase, React calls render and then compares the result to the previous render.
- The **Commit phase** is when React applies any changes. (In the case of React DOM, this is when React inserts, updates, and removes DOM nodes.) React also calls lifecycles like componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate during this phase.

The commit phase is usually very fast, but rendering can be slow. For this reason, the upcoming concurrent mode (which is not enabled by default yet) breaks the rendering work into pieces, pausing and resuming the work to avoid blocking the browser. This means that React may invoke render phase lifecycles more than once before committing, or it may invoke them without committing at all (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).

Learn More [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) from the official docs.

Look at [this](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) component life cycle graph for clear understanding.

Comment: @Bilal if you think you've got your answer, can you mark the answer as correct and close the question. Thanks. Upvote would be appreciated.